# Possible to have user components within class library and call them from that library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class, components

Is there a way to have following ?

**CLASS**

- ucComponent.ascx
- Component.cs

and then within Component.cs to dynamically create component, generate content and send to program which called it as finalized string.

```
CLASS tmpClass = new CLASS();
string strResult = string.Empty;
strResult = tmpClass.Generate();
```

Reason for this? I want to have unified components within class library and on client-end generate content and use CSS for styling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have user controls in a separate library, because of the ASCX markup file they need to sit in the web app project.

Comment: what would be the best solution to have what i need? do I need manually create HTML code I need in stringbuilder and return back ?

Comment: You can have server controls in a separate library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx I have used them in exactly the way you describe to create a "form rendering" application where the controls on the page were determined by data in a database.